# CMake Custom Command Depending On Variable

Tags: cmake

Part of my build process requires passing in a variable to a script to generate some source files. It looks something like this:

```
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT
        rebuild_files
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo
        COMMENT "Force rebuild of generated files"
    )

    add_custom_command(OUTPUT "File.c" "File.h"
        COMMAND ruby generate_files.rb ${OPTIONS_LIST}
        COMMENT "Generate files"
        DEPENDS rebuild_files
    )
```

Of course, this runs on every compilation, which isn't needed. The `OPTIONS_LIST` is set up at configuration time, so it could be cached.

Is there a mechanism to make a custom command dependent on a variable? The ultimate goal is to have this only compile if:

1. `OPTIONS_LIST` changes.
2. `File.c` or `File.h` do not exist.

Comment: Unlike to the **files**, which can be modified by a user or updated by another command, "dependency from **variable**" is not well-defined: Content of the variable isn't come from the thin air, but calculated based on files or other information sources. So, how the value of `OPTIONS_LIST` variable is calculated in your case? What are dependencies of such calculation?

Comment: `OPTIONS_LIST` is created at the time of CMake's configuration. For example:

`cmake -G Xcode .. -DOPTIONS_LIST=a,b,c,d`

We use those options to generate a C file, which considers the list and the order they are in.

Answer (score 4):

Using `configure_file` one may convert "dependency from the variable" to "dependency from the file" which is naturally handled by custom target/command:

**options_list_file.in**:

```
${OPTIONS_LIST}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# Variable which can be modified by a user
set(OPTIONS_LIST "a,b" CACHE STRING "<description>")
# Configure file which will be updated on changing the variable's content
configure_file("options_list_file.in" "options_list_file")

add_custom_command(OUTPUT "File.c" "File.h"
    COMMAND ruby generate_files.rb ${OPTIONS_LIST}
    COMMENT "Generate files"
    DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINART_DIR}/options_list_file" # dependency from the file
)
```

Changing the `OPTIONS_LIST` variable implies re-running CMake (*configuration stage*). Upon that re-run the `configure_file` will be called *unconditionally*.

But the file `options_list_file` will be updated only when its content would be changed. This is a main feature of `configure_file`.

That is, if the variable is set by a user to another value, then `options_list_file` will be updated, and this triggers re-running custom COMMAND on next build.

But if the variable's content is not changed, then `configure_file` wouldn't change the file `options_list_file` and its timestamp (this is important!). So, next build won't treat the file as updated and won't trigger the COMMAND re-run.